# Nested object text search in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, search

I am not sure how I am going to solve this problem:
I want to search in a mongoDB collection and return only the nested objects that fits the search query (using text search on all of the fields).

All documents in the collection have this format:

```
{
  arr: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'Random',
      description: 'Hello world'
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'World',
      description: 'This is a random description'
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: 'Random',
      description: 'Hi'
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case, if my search query is 'world', then this should be the result:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Random',
    description: 'Hello world'
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'World',
    description: 'This is a random description'
  },
  //... objects from other documents in the collection that fits the query
]
```

If this is not possible in mongoDB, are there any JavaScript libraries that can achieve this? Would greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the aggregation framework it could look like so

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$arr'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                { 'arr.name': /world/i },
                { 'arr.description': /world/i }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$arr._id',
            name: '$arr.name',
            description: '$arr.description'
        }
    }
])
```

which will result in the following output for your example data:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Random",
    "description" : "Hello world"
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "World",
    "description" : "This is a random description"
}
```

If you have the need for a single array with the resulting documents as shown in your question, you can simply chain a `toArray()` call at the end of the pipeline - keep in mind though that this may cause increased memory consumption in case of large result sets as pointed out by [SSDMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100115/ssdms) in the comments.

Comment: Why to you need `toArray()` here?

Comment: To *exactly* match his desired result

Comment: [`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) loads all the documents into RAM. what is it useful for here? **NOTHING**

Comment: I agree that toArray() is usually not necessary but wanted to match the result to be as close to the desired result as possible - which admittedly is wrong in this case as users may think one absolutely has to use it. I updated the answer accordingly and hope we got a suitable compromise :)