# Mongodb search text in specific documents' field in a collection

Tags: database, mongodb

My databse is on Mongodb Atlas, and I'm trying to search for a keyword (input by the user) within a field of all documents of a collection.

**Structure:**

collection is "Users"

documents inside are about 500

each document has among others a field named "videos" which looks like:

```
videos (array)
   0: (object)
     title: (string)
     views: (number)
     duration: (number)
   1: (object)
     etc.
```

so that if let's say `videos[0].title` contains the keyword the query returns the whole `videos[0]` and other fields of the related document.

What I tried so far is 1: creating a text index within the `Users` collection for the field videos and do:

```
const searchVideos = await db.collection('Users').find({
$text: { $search: keyword }
}).project({
videos: 1, username: 1, image: 1, _id: 0
}).toArray()
```

result: `undefined`

2: I tried via regex as:

```
const searchVideos = await db.collection('Users').find({
"videos.$.title" : {$regex : keyword}
}).project({
videos: 1, username: 1, image: 1, _id: 0
}).toArray()
```

result: `undefined`

3: I tried to create a Search index (Search tab of the collection on Mongo Atlas) with the field videos set, and following the documentation I did:

```
const searchVideos = await db.collection('Users').aggregate([
        {
          $search: {
            "text": {
              "query": keyword,
              "path": "videos"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 5
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "videos": 1,
            "username": 1,
            "image": 1
          }
        }
    ])
```

result: `undefined`

the console.log which returns undefined is:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(searchVideos[0]))
```

where am I doing wrong?

simplied playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZhgxF-Dei2l

mongodb compass screenshot for my collection indexes:
[image]

**UPDATE:** from my understanding, the method suggested below works in the sense that it does the search, the problem relies with the mongodb search itself, since it's basically acting this way: you search for a video with `.title` containing the keyword searched but it returns the whole document (or all the videos of that document if `.project(videos: 1)` is used. From what I've seen there's no way to specify the query to retrieve that video object only instead of all the videos (what I tried is `.project("videos.$": 1)` successfully used elsewhere before but throwing an error if used with $text $search)

**UPDATE 2**: found how to achieve it via regex here: [Nested object text search in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410763/nested-object-text-search-in-mongodb)

but if anyone knows how to achieve the same with the $text search I'll assign the bounty cause it'd be much better in terms of query speed I guess

Comment: Missing MCVE using mongo shell.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZhgxF-Dei2l

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a text index on `videos.title` like this:

```
db.stores.createIndex( { "videos.title": "text" } )
```

then, tou can query it like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$text": {
    "$search": "test"
  }
})
```

working playgound: [mongoplayground.net/p/Ji2zSCL-T7W](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ji2zSCL-T7W)

Comment: I tried that, and it searches text in username instead of videos title

Comment: In your playground there is no higher level fields like username (string): "test this" , i'm sure if you add it and search for "test" it will get that instead. I'm trying to figure out how this nightmare of a simulator works

Comment: Better, it searches video titles too, but it gives priority to usernames if he finds the keyword in there too

Comment: @m4tt `$search` search in all indexed field.  If there's match on `username`, it means there's a text index on it
You can check your indexes with `db.collection.getIndexes()`

Comment: Only videos and "_ id_" are set as indexes, among which only videos is a text index. Altough I noticed that while "_ id_" has linked the "_id" field, which is a field present in the documents, my textindex has "_fts  _ftsx" fields, which I don't really know what are. Also as of now the search really sucks, it find 60% of the titles without even the keyword inside but I think is all related